# Inserting a link to an application in SharePoint

Tags: integration

Is it possible to insert a link to an application(s) stored on a network into a sharepoint site?

I've tried the page viewer webpart, but this only works for files/folders and does not display the application(s) icon.  Essentially I want users to be able to open sharepoint and launch the application(s) from there.

Any suggestions would be grately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this is to use custom content type. Just create a list in your sharepoint site with content type as Link. You can do this by Creating new content type from `Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Content Types -> Create,` and there select `List Content Type -> Link (parent content type).`  Now your lists can hold link  to a Web page or other resource.